# Ошибки при работе с google/cloud-vision PHP - Fail to push limit

Tags: php, google-cloud

Установил google/cloud-vision через композер
Устанавливаю переменную окружения с путем до файла с ключем, выполняю код из примера:

```
use Google\Cloud\Vision\V1\ImageAnnotatorClient;
putenv("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/json.json");
$imageAnnotator = new ImageAnnotatorClient();
$fileName = 'textinjpeg.jpg';
$image = file_get_contents($fileName);
$response = $imageAnnotator->labelDetection($image);
$labels = $response->getLabelAnnotations();
if ($labels) {
    echo("Labels:" . PHP_EOL);
    foreach ($labels as $label) {
        echo($label->getDescription() . PHP_EOL);
    }
} else {
    echo('No label found' . PHP_EOL);
}
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
    Error occurred during parsing: Fail to push limit. (0)
/srv/www/site.ru/htdocs/vendor/google/protobuf/src/Google/Protobuf/Internal/CodedInputStream.php:345
#0: Google\Protobuf\Internal\CodedInputStream-&gt;pushLimit(integer)
    /srv/www/site.ru/htdocs/vendor/google/protobuf/src/Google/Protobuf/Internal/CodedInputStream.php:368
#1: Google\Protobuf\Internal\CodedInputStream-&gt;incrementRecursionDepthAndPushLimit(integer, integer, integer)
    /srv/www/site.ru/htdocs/vendor/google/protobuf/src/Google/Protobuf/Internal/GPBWire.php:288
#2: Google\Protobuf\Internal\GPBWire::readMessage(object, object)
    /srv/www/site.ru/htdocs/vendor/google/protobuf/src/Google/Protobuf/Internal/Message.php:420
#3: Google\Protobuf\Internal\Message::parseFieldFromStreamNoTag(object, object, object)
    /srv/www/site.ru/htdocs/vendor/google/protobuf/src/Google/Protobuf/Internal/Message.php:500
#4: Google\Protobuf\Internal\Message-&gt;parseFieldFromStream(integer, object, object)
    /srv/www/site.ru/htdocs/vendor/google/protobuf/src/Google/Protobuf/Internal/Message.php:796
#5: Google\Protobuf\Internal\Message-&gt;parseFromStream(object)
    /srv/www/site.ru/htdocs/vendor/google/protobuf/src/Google/Protobuf/Internal/Message.php:760
    /srv/www/site.ru/htdocs/vendor/google/protobuf/src/Google/Protobuf/Internal/DescriptorPool.php:61
#7: Google\Protobuf\Internal\DescriptorPool-&gt;internalAddGeneratedFile(string, boolean)
    /srv/www/site.ru/htdocs/vendor/google/common-protos/metadata/Api/Annotations.php:26
#8: GPBMetadata\Google\Api\Annotations::initOnce()
    /srv/www/site.ru/htdocs/vendor/google/cloud-vision/metadata/V1/ImageAnnotator.php:17
#9: GPBMetadata\Google\Cloud\Vision\V1\ImageAnnotator::initOnce()
    /srv/www/site.ru/htdocs/vendor/google/cloud-vision/src/V1/Image.php:52
#10: Google\Cloud\Vision\V1\Image-&gt;__construct()
    /srv/www/site.ru/htdocs/vendor/google/cloud-vision/src/VisionHelpersTrait.php:101
#11: Google\Cloud\Vision\V1\ImageAnnotatorClient-&gt;createImageHelper(string, string, string)
    /srv/www/site.ru/htdocs/vendor/google/cloud-vision/src/V1/ImageAnnotatorClient.php:82
#12: Google\Cloud\Vision\V1\ImageAnnotatorClient-&gt;createImageObject(string)
    /srv/www/site.ru/htdocs/vendor/google/cloud-vision/src/V1/ImageAnnotatorClient.php:118
#13: Google\Cloud\Vision\V1\ImageAnnotatorClient-&gt;annotateImage(string, array, array)
    /srv/www/site.ru/htdocs/vendor/google/cloud-vision/src/V1/ImageAnnotatorClient.php:575
#14: Google\Cloud\Vision\V1\ImageAnnotatorClient-&gt;annotateSingleFeature(string, integer, array)
    /srv/www/site.ru/htdocs/vendor/google/cloud-vision/src/V1/ImageAnnotatorClient.php:264
#15: Google\Cloud\Vision\V1\ImageAnnotatorClient-&gt;labelDetection(string)
    /srv/www/site.ru/htdocs/local/php_interface/GoogleCloud.php:41
```

Исключение выбрасывается тут:

```
public function pushLimit($byte_limit)
{
    // Current position relative to the beginning of the stream.
    $current_position = $this->current();
    $old_limit = $this->current_limit;

    // security: byte_limit is possibly evil, so check for negative values
    // and overflow.
    if ($byte_limit >= 0 &&
        $byte_limit <= PHP_INT_MAX - $current_position &&
        $byte_limit <= $this->current_limit - $current_position) {
        $this->current_limit = $current_position + $byte_limit;
        $this->recomputeBufferLimits();
    } else {
        throw new GPBDecodeException("Fail to push limit.");
    }

    return $old_limit;
}
```

Если пропустить это условие и всегда выполнять

```
$this->current_limit = $current_position + $byte_limit;
$this->recomputeBufferLimits();
```

то дальше вылазит ошибка:

```
    Expect utf-8 encoding. (0)
/srv/www/site.ru/htdocs/vendor/google/protobuf/src/Google/Protobuf/Internal/GPBUtil.php:108
#0: Google\Protobuf\Internal\GPBUtil::checkString(string, boolean)
    /srv/www/site.ru/htdocs/vendor/google/protobuf/src/Google/Protobuf/Internal/FileOptions.php:549
#1: Google\Protobuf\Internal\FileOptions-&gt;setGoPackage(string)
    /srv/www/site.ru/htdocs/vendor/google/protobuf/src/Google/Protobuf/Internal/Message.php:525
#2: Google\Protobuf\Internal\Message-&gt;parseFieldFromStream(integer, object, object)
    /srv/www/site.ru/htdocs/vendor/google/protobuf/src/Google/Protobuf/Internal/Message.php:796
#3: Google\Protobuf\Internal\Message-&gt;parseFromStream(object)
    /srv/www/site.ru/htdocs/vendor/google/protobuf/src/Google/Protobuf/Internal/GPBWire.php:289
#4: Google\Protobuf\Internal\GPBWire::readMessage(object, object)
    /srv/www/site.ru/htdocs/vendor/google/protobuf/src/Google/Protobuf/Internal/Message.php:420
#5: Google\Protobuf\Internal\Message::parseFieldFromStreamNoTag(object, object, object)
    /srv/www/site.ru/htdocs/vendor/google/protobuf/src/Google/Protobuf/Internal/Message.php:500
#6: Google\Protobuf\Internal\Message-&gt;parseFieldFromStream(integer, object, object)
    /srv/www/site.ru/htdocs/vendor/google/protobuf/src/Google/Protobuf/Internal/Message.php:796
#7: Google\Protobuf\Internal\Message-&gt;parseFromStream(object)
    /srv/www/site.ru/htdocs/vendor/google/protobuf/src/Google/Protobuf/Internal/GPBWire.php:289
#8: Google\Protobuf\Internal\GPBWire::readMessage(object, object)
    /srv/www/site.ru/htdocs/vendor/google/protobuf/src/Google/Protobuf/Internal/Message.php:420
#9: Google\Protobuf\Internal\Message::parseFieldFromStreamNoTag(object, object, object)
    /srv/www/site.ru/htdocs/vendor/google/protobuf/src/Google/Protobuf/Internal/Message.php:500
#10: Google\Protobuf\Internal\Message-&gt;parseFieldFromStream(integer, object, object)
    /srv/www/site.ru/htdocs/vendor/google/protobuf/src/Google/Protobuf/Internal/Message.php:796
#11: Google\Protobuf\Internal\Message-&gt;parseFromStream(object)
    /srv/www/site.ru/htdocs/vendor/google/protobuf/src/Google/Protobuf/Internal/Message.php:760
#12: Google\Protobuf\Internal\Message-&gt;mergeFromString(string)
    /srv/www/site.ru/htdocs/vendor/google/protobuf/src/Google/Protobuf/Internal/DescriptorPool.php:61
#13: Google\Protobuf\Internal\DescriptorPool-&gt;internalAddGeneratedFile(string, boolean)
    /srv/www/site.ru/htdocs/vendor/google/common-protos/metadata/Api/Annotations.php:26
#14: GPBMetadata\Google\Api\Annotations::initOnce()
    /srv/www/site.ru/htdocs/vendor/google/cloud-vision/metadata/V1/ImageAnnotator.php:17
#15: GPBMetadata\Google\Cloud\Vision\V1\ImageAnnotator::initOnce()
    /srv/www/site.ru/htdocs/vendor/google/cloud-vision/src/V1/Image.php:52
#16: Google\Cloud\Vision\V1\Image-&gt;__construct()
    /srv/www/site.ru/htdocs/vendor/google/cloud-vision/src/VisionHelpersTrait.php:101
#17: Google\Cloud\Vision\V1\ImageAnnotatorClient-&gt;createImageHelper(string, string, boolean)
    /srv/www/site.ru/htdocs/vendor/google/cloud-vision/src/V1/ImageAnnotatorClient.php:82
#18: Google\Cloud\Vision\V1\ImageAnnotatorClient-&gt;createImageObject(boolean)
    /srv/www/site.ru/htdocs/vendor/google/cloud-vision/src/V1/ImageAnnotatorClient.php:118
#19: Google\Cloud\Vision\V1\ImageAnnotatorClient-&gt;annotateImage(boolean, array, array)
    /srv/www/site.ru/htdocs/vendor/google/cloud-vision/src/V1/ImageAnnotatorClient.php:575
#20: Google\Cloud\Vision\V1\ImageAnnotatorClient-&gt;annotateSingleFeature(boolean, integer, array)
    /srv/www/site.ru/htdocs/vendor/google/cloud-vision/src/V1/ImageAnnotatorClient.php:264
#21: Google\Cloud\Vision\V1\ImageAnnotatorClient-&gt;labelDetection(boolean)
    /srv/www/site.ru/htdocs/local/php_interface/GoogleCloud.php:38
```

Исключение выбрасывается тут:

```
public static function checkString(&$var, $check_utf8)
{
    if (is_array($var) || is_object($var)) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Expect string.");
    }
    if (!is_string($var)) {
        $var = strval($var);
    }
    if ($check_utf8 && !preg_match('//u', $var)) {
        throw new \Exception("Expect utf-8 encoding.");
    }
}
```

Сюда в переменной var попадают по очереди следующие значения:

```
google/api/http.proto
google.api
Http
rules
.google.api.HttpRule
fully_decode_reserved_expansion
HttpRule
selector
get
put
post
delete
patch
custom
.google.api.CustomHttpPattern
body
response_body
additional_bindings
.google.api.HttpRule
pattern
CustomHttpPattern
kind
path
com.google.api
HttpProto
google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/api/annotations;annotations
GAPI
proto3
oogle/api/annotations.proto
oogle.api
oogle/protobuf/descriptor.protoB
om.google.apiB
nnotationsProtoP
oogle.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/api/annotations;annotations�
```

Если в этом месте менять кодировку, то после 'oogle.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/api/annotations;annotations?' еще приходит 'APIb' и затем вылетает ошибка:

```
    [Google\Protobuf\Internal\GPBDecodeException] 
Error occurred during parsing: Unexpected EOF inside string field. (0)
/srv/www/site.ru/htdocs/vendor/google/protobuf/src/Google/Protobuf/Internal/Message.php:406
#0: Google\Protobuf\Internal\Message::parseFieldFromStreamNoTag(object, object, NULL)
    /srv/www/site.ru/htdocs/vendor/google/protobuf/src/Google/Protobuf/Internal/Message.php:500
#1: Google\Protobuf\Internal\Message-&gt;parseFieldFromStream(integer, object, object)
    /srv/www/site.ru/htdocs/vendor/google/protobuf/src/Google/Protobuf/Internal/Message.php:796
#2: Google\Protobuf\Internal\Message-&gt;parseFromStream(object)
    /srv/www/site.ru/htdocs/vendor/google/protobuf/src/Google/Protobuf/Internal/GPBWire.php:289
#3: Google\Protobuf\Internal\GPBWire::readMessage(object, object)
    /srv/www/site.ru/htdocs/vendor/google/protobuf/src/Google/Protobuf/Internal/Message.php:420
#4: Google\Protobuf\Internal\Message::parseFieldFromStreamNoTag(object, object, object)
    /srv/www/site.ru/htdocs/vendor/google/protobuf/src/Google/Protobuf/Internal/Message.php:500
#5: Google\Protobuf\Internal\Message-&gt;parseFieldFromStream(integer, object, object)
    /srv/www/site.ru/htdocs/vendor/google/protobuf/src/Google/Protobuf/Internal/Message.php:796
#6: Google\Protobuf\Internal\Message-&gt;parseFromStream(object)
    /srv/www/site.ru/htdocs/vendor/google/protobuf/src/Google/Protobuf/Internal/Message.php:760
#7: Google\Protobuf\Internal\Message-&gt;mergeFromString(string)
    /srv/www/site.ru/htdocs/vendor/google/protobuf/src/Google/Protobuf/Internal/DescriptorPool.php:61
#8: Google\Protobuf\Internal\DescriptorPool-&gt;internalAddGeneratedFile(string, boolean)
    /srv/www/site.ru/htdocs/vendor/google/common-protos/metadata/Api/Annotations.php:26
#9: GPBMetadata\Google\Api\Annotations::initOnce()
    /srv/www/site.ru/htdocs/vendor/google/cloud-vision/metadata/V1/ImageAnnotator.php:17
#10: GPBMetadata\Google\Cloud\Vision\V1\ImageAnnotator::initOnce()
    /srv/www/site.ru/htdocs/vendor/google/cloud-vision/src/V1/Image.php:52
#11: Google\Cloud\Vision\V1\Image-&gt;__construct()
    /srv/www/site.ru/htdocs/vendor/google/cloud-vision/src/VisionHelpersTrait.php:101
#12: Google\Cloud\Vision\V1\ImageAnnotatorClient-&gt;createImageHelper(string, string, boolean)
    /srv/www/site.ru/htdocs/vendor/google/cloud-vision/src/V1/ImageAnnotatorClient.php:82
#13: Google\Cloud\Vision\V1\ImageAnnotatorClient-&gt;createImageObject(boolean)
    /srv/www/site.ru/htdocs/vendor/google/cloud-vision/src/V1/ImageAnnotatorClient.php:118
#14: Google\Cloud\Vision\V1\ImageAnnotatorClient-&gt;annotateImage(boolean, array, array)
    /srv/www/site.ru/htdocs/vendor/google/cloud-vision/src/V1/ImageAnnotatorClient.php:575
#15: Google\Cloud\Vision\V1\ImageAnnotatorClient-&gt;annotateSingleFeature(boolean, integer, array)
    /srv/www/site.ru/htdocs/vendor/google/cloud-vision/src/V1/ImageAnnotatorClient.php:264
#16: Google\Cloud\Vision\V1\ImageAnnotatorClient-&gt;labelDetection(boolean)
    /srv/www/site.ru/htdocs/local/php_interface/GoogleCloud.php:38
```

Кто-нибудь сталкивался? Полагаю, что корень зла лежит именно в $byte_limit из \Google\Protobuf\Internal\CodedInputStream::pushLimit, потому что потом начинаются обрезаться строки, которые приходят в \Google\Protobuf\Internal\GPBUtil::checkString

Answer (score 0):

Решение: mbstring.func_overload 0

Comment: Будет более полезным написать подробно где Вы использовали даную конструкцию для решения возникшей у Вас проблемы.